# How do get layout in magento2?

Tags: layout, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

how do get layout in magento 2 in  custom module same 
[image]

**Edit**
this code

```
<?php
namespace Addon\Gallery\Block\Adminhtml\Gallery\Gallery;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container;
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container 
{   


    protected $_layoutFactory;
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, 
         \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,         
         \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        array $data =[]     
    )
    {
        $this->_layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

      parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }
     public function getPage(){

        return $this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->getOptions();         
     }


}
```

**Show error**

```
Notice: Undefined property: Addon\Gallery\Block\Adminhtml\Gallery\Gallery\Edit::$pageLayoutBuilder in C:\localhost\magento2_beta\app\code\Addon\Gallery\Block\Adminhtml\Gallery\Gallery\Edit.php
```

Comment: is this a field on your custom entity? or you need the list of layouts?

Comment: you can get layout using below code: `$this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->getOptions()`

Comment: @Marius I want create function get list of layouts.

Comment: @AmitBera Notice: Undefined property: Addon\Gallery\Block\Adminhtml\Gallery\Gallery\Edit::$pageLayoutBuilder.

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: I edited question @AmitBera.

Answer (score 4):

Add this above your class

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface;
```

then add these members in your class

```
/**
 * @var BuilderInterface
 */
protected $pageLayoutBuilder;
/**
 * @var array|null
 */
protected $options;
```

Then in the constructor inject an instance of `BuilderInterface`

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    BuilderInterface $pageLayoutBuilder
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->pageLayoutBuilder = $pageLayoutBuilder;
    ....
}
```

now add this method to your class

```
public function getLayoutOptions($withEmpty = true)
{
    if (is_null($this->options)) {
        $_options = $this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->toOptionArray();
        foreach ($_options as $option) {
            $this->options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
    }
    $options = $this->options;
    if ($withEmpty) {
        $options = array_merge([''=>''], $options);
    }
    return $options;
}
```

now you can call `$this->getLayoutOptions()` anywhere you need the layout options.

Comment: How do get Current Category layout value e.g if is "1 column" or "2 column and so on.. can you help at all thanks ."?